# How to remove certain strings from a list in python

Tags: python, string, list

If I have a list similar to

```py
mylist = ["danny","florence","micheal","klrv","yrcv"]
```

And I want to remove the strings that do not have vowels in them and put them in a new list, resulting in me have two lists. How do I do it?

I tried coding it manually

```py
mylist_no_vowel = ["klrv","yrcv"]
```

Then using `.remove` to make original list smaller.
But I feel there is a code to automate it instead of doing it manually.

Comment: Don't call your list `list`, it overrides the builtin `list` function.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick-and-dirty one-liner is:

```
mylist = ["danny","florence","micheal","klrv","yrcv"]
mylist_no_vowel = [word for word in mylist if not any(character in 'aeiou' for character in word)]
```

#### Explanation

The second line uses a syntax called a list comprehension, which is a  Python idiom for building a list (in this case, by filtering another list). The code is equivalent to:

```
mylist = ["danny","florence","micheal","klrv","yrcv"]
mylist_no_vowel = []

for word in mylist:
    if not any(character in 'aeiou' for character in word):
        mylist_no_vowel.append(word)
```

Translating, we start an empty list called `mylist_no_vowel`, then we iterate through each word in the original list `mylist`. For each word, we check if any of their characters is a vowel, using the `any` function. If that's not the case, we add the word to the `mylist_no_vowel` list.

Note that I changed your starting list variable name from `list` to `mylist`, since `list` is actually a reserved word in Python - you're overwriting the built-in list function by naming a variable like that!

Comment: Hi, this works absolutely fine, but when i want to use mylist. It still includes those two strings. I'm just going to use the .remove function to get those strings out

Comment: Also, i did't know but i have changed it now to mylist

Comment: You can create a third list (e.g. `mylist_only_vowel`) for storing all words with at least one vowel simply by removing the word `not` from my example. This is probably easier than trying to directly recycle `mylist`.

Answer (score 2):

The following codes should serve the purpose.

```
mylist = ["danny", "florence", "micheal", "klrv", "yrcv"]

mylist_no_vowel = list(filter(lambda x: set('aeiou') & set(x)==set(), mylist))

print(mylist_no_vowel)
```

Here is the result, which is the same as your expected result:

```
['klrv', 'yrcv']
```

The idea is to use the anonymous function to filter out each element `x` of `mylist` that contains vowels via keeping each element `x` of `mylist` such that the intersection of `set(x)` and `set('aeiou')` is the empty set `set()`.